# Edit the .config file when en/disabling a particular option like CONFIG_CPU_FREQ?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, configuration

From here: http://www.xenomai.org/index.php/FAQs#Which_kernel_settings_should_be_avoided.3F

> Which kernel settings should be avoided?
>   Note that Xenomai will warn you about known invalid combinations during kernel configuration.
>   - CONFIG_CPU_FREQ
>   - CONFIG_APM
>   - CONFIG_ACPI_PROCESSOR

Now, when I look in the `.config`, I do find these options clearly but I don't know their dependencies.

So, it is wise to simply put a `n` next to these options in the `.config` file?
Will the make procedure take care of the dependencies?

The `make menuconfig` window do not present these options *explicitly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make menuconfig` does present this option. If you are in the menu press <kbd>/</kbd> and search for `CPU_FREQ`. This will show all `CONFIG` parameters containing `CPU_FREQ`. It does also show how you can access it through the menu, e.g:

```
│ Symbol: CPU_FREQ [=y]  
│ Type  : boolean
│ Prompt: CPU Frequency scaling
│   Defined at drivers/cpufreq/Kconfig:3
│   Location:
│     -> Power management and ACPI options
│       -> CPU Frequency scaling
```

This means you find it under `Power managment and ACPI options` -> `CPU Frequency scaling` and the name of the entry is `CPU Frequency scaling`.

Comment: actually, it was my fault. I was looking for exactly for the term: "CONFIG_CPU_FREQ". I realized later on that it is the "prompt" that we have to look for: "CPU Frequency scaling".